# Query of line direction histogram plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, vector, histogram

I was wondering if anyone could explain how this plugin works I have had a play around with it and I do like how it visualizes how vectors are orientated. However I ran one and opened the CSV file showing the total vector length and the number of vectors within a segment (in total 16 segments/bins).

My question is how does this plugin identify which vectors go into each segment and is there a way of identifying which vectors(in particular the vector id) fall into particular histogram segments as I would like to then use this information for further analysis these vectors and accompany the results with the line direction histogram graph

Comment: http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/LineDirectionHistogram/